# Calling static method by reflection is thread safe in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, reflection, thread-safety

Is this code thread safe ?

create runnable and invoke a method by reflection :

```
 public class A {
    public static void  someMethod (List<VO> voList){
        int endIndex=0;
        for (int firstIndex = 0; firstIndex < voList.size(); ) {
            endIndex = Math.min(firstIndex + threadSize, voList.size());
            Runner runner = null;
            try {
                runner = new Runner(voList.subList(firstIndex, endIndex),
                                    B.class.getMethod("createSomeString", D.class));
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                log.warn(ex.getMessage());
            }
            //start a thread
            runner.start();
        }

    }

    private static class Runner extends Thread {
        private Method method;
        private List<C> list;
        public Runner(Method method,List<C> clist) {
            this.method = method;
            this.list=clist;
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        for (C vo: list) {                
            String xml = (String) method.invoke(null,vo);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call a static method by reflection ,is this code block thread safe ?

```
   public class B {
   public static String createSomeString(D a) throws Exception {
     return a.name;
   }
   }
```

and D.class is Plain old java object class like this :

```
   public class D implements Serializable{
   private String name;
   }
```

Comment: Please format your code better so we can read it

Comment: Is this one question? Two? Thread-safety depends on the method itself, not on Reflection.

Comment: Making a method call via reflection is not more or less thread safe than just calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using static variables inside the method, or anything else that needs to be thread safe, the `synchronized` keyword is one option.

```
   public class B {
       public synchronized String createSomeString(A a) throws Exception {
         return a.name;
       }
   }
```

Another option would be to use a queue with a pool size of one. Google has a good example project available for this available at: [Running Code on a Thread Pool Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html)

If it's `a.name` that may be accessed by multiple threads then you'll want to synchronize that instead.

```
   public class B {
       public static String createSomeString(A a) throws Exception {
         String strName = "";
         synchronize (a.name) {
             strName = new String(a.name);
         }
         return strName;
       }
   }
```

Comment: in class b I use static member but it is final .should I synchronize createSomeString method ?

Answer (score -2):

You only doing read operation in your static method, so it's thread safe no matter how much concurrent your program is. if both read and write involved, then you have to synchronize your static method or code block.

Answer (score -3):

Use volatile. Please click here to know about  http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html

Comment: How is that related? There isn't any class or instance variable in the example.